# A better solution for my approach to create procedure Rand(a,b), using procedure Rand(0,1)

Tags: c, algorithm, random, big-o, clrs

I have been reading CLRS and encountered the problem to write a procedure Rand(a,b) which generates a random number between a to b uniformly at random, using a procedure Rand(0,1) which generates 0 or 1 with 50% probability.

I have thought of the following solution, which is O(b) in time:

```
int Rand_a_b(int a,int b)
{
    int i,k=0;
    for(i=0;i<b-a;i++)
    {
         k+=Rand(0,1);
    }
    return a+k;
}
```

Please suggest a better approach to this.

Comment: your function does not generate a uniform distribution, plus it assumes `b` is greater than `a` unsafely.

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: Why does it not give a uniform distribution? Please elaborate.

Comment: Let's say `a == 0` and `b == 2`. You get `0` with probability `1/4`, `2` with probability `1/4` and `1` with probability `1/2`.

Comment: and more generally: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the number of distinct numbers in the range is not a power of two, you have to be careful, because any procedure which always takes N numbers sees only 2^N different possibilities, and it will not be possible to distribute 2^N different possibilities evenly over a range if the range does not have a power of two different possibilities.

One approach when generating numbers between a..b is to use k random numbers as individual bits in a k-bit number to produce a number in the range a..a+2^k-1, where k is chosen so that a+2^k-1 >= b. If it turns out that the random number you have produced is out of range, start again from scratch. This dodges the problem above by taking a variable number of random bits, depending on whether and how often you generate something out of range and have to start again.

Answer (score 1):

here is an algorithm: calculate the difference between a and b: `k = abs(a-b)` and start doing a binary search like so:

keep a number `n = 0`.flip your coin - `Rand(0,1)`, if the outcome is 1 add `k/2` to your `n` else add nothing. than flip it again for `k/4` and repeat until `k/i` is 0.

Comment: Distribution will not be uniform if `b - a + 1` is not a power of two.

Comment: @AlexD - this was general pseudocode. the issue of how to deal with uneven numbers etc. is not covered by this obviously.

Answer (score 1):

That here should make it in log(n). *(I didn't check for boundaries, its not tested!)*
You can't make it faster that that - if you emit only one bit a time, you need at least log(b-a) rounds for an interval.

```
function Rand_a_b(int a, int b) {
   if (a == b) return a;
   int middle = (b-a)/2;
   if (Rand(0,1)) {
      return Rand_a_b(middle + 1, b);
   } else {
      return Rand_a_b(a, middle);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah indeed emitting bits is the way to go !

Comment: It will work if `(b - a + 1)` is power of `2`. If `a == 0` and `b == 2` then `2` is selected with probability `1/2`; `0` and `1` are selected with probability `1/4`.